# R canonical dplyr way of replace if

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose you have:

```
df = data.frame(a = c(1,2,NA),b = c(NA, 1,2))
> df
   a  b
1  1 NA
2  2  1
3 NA  2
```

and wish to create a new column c based on a. If a is missing, then use b. This works:

```
df %>% mutate(c= a,
              c = replace(c, is.na(a), b[is.na(a)]))
```

but (to me, just me?) looks clumsy (in the sense that I have to spell out `is.na(a)` twice). This is easier:

```
df %>%
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(c = a,
          c = replace(c, is.na(a), b]))
```

but it requires the extra `rowwise()` command, and I could imagine situatoins where sum of my `mutate` statesments will not work rowwise.

Am I missing a some `dplyr` feature that makes this (very common task?) easier?

Comment: a simple `ifelse` ? `df %>%  mutate(c = ifelse(is.na(a), b, a))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this, you can use `coalesce()` from `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
 mutate(c = coalesce(a, b))

   a  b c
1  1 NA 1
2  2  1 2
3 NA  2 2
```

From the documentation:

> Given a set of vectors, coalesce() finds the first non-missing value
>   at each position.

Or if you want to apply it on the whole df:

```
df %>%
 mutate(c = coalesce(!!!.))
```